# Generalised eigenvalue problem: form a basis in $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a generalised eigenvalue problem for two real symmetric $N\times N$ matrices $A$ and $B$
$$
(A-\lambda B)\cdot\mathbf{x}_{\lambda}=0\,.
$$

Assume that $A$ and $B$ have non-zero determinants. I am interested in the case where neither $A$ or $B$ are positive definite, so that complex eigenvalues $\lambda$ can exist. Consider the case where $n_R$ eigenvalues are real, and $n_C$ are complex, so that $n_R+2 n_C=N$ (the factor of two arises because complex eigenvalues come in pairs). In general. the eigenvectors associated with the $n_C$ complex eigenvalues will be complex. Denote the complex eigenvectors by $\mathbf{y}_{\lambda_C}$ and the eigenvectors associated with the real eigenvalues by $\mathbf{x}_{\lambda_R}$.

Take the set of $N$ vectors $\{\mathbf{x}_{\lambda_R},\mathrm{Re}(\mathbf{y}_{\lambda_C}),\mathrm{Im}(\mathbf{y}_{\lambda_C})\}$. Do these form a basis in $\mathbb{R}^N$? I have tried this with many examples and it appears correct, but so far a general proof seems illusive.

**Example:**

Consider
$$
A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 3 & 4 \\
 3 & 2 & 0 \\
 4 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)\,,\quad B = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 2 & 0 \\
 2 & -5 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\,.
$$
Both $A$ and $B$ are symmetric real $3\times 3$ matrices and have non-zero determinants. $\lambda$ can be determined via
$$
9 \lambda ^3-33 \lambda ^2-43 \lambda -46=0\,.
$$
It is simple to see that two of the roots of the above polynomial are complex. If you form the set of eigevectors as described above, they also form a basis.

Comment: Remember that $N$ vectors almost always form a basis unless there is a reason they shouldn't.  Trying cases to find one where they do not is probably not a good approach.  Perhaps better would be to take $N=3$ and three dependent vectors and try to construct $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Take $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=I$. The eigenvectors does not form a basis in $\mathbb{R}^N$. Maybe you are trying to ask something different?

Comment: Thank you for both your comments. Obareey, the point is that your $A$ is not symmetric, that is why you don't get a basis.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but some observations that are a bit long for a comment.

1. Since $B$ has a nonzero determinant, it is invertible. Thus,
   $$(A-\lambda B)x = 0 \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad (B^{-1}A-\lambda I)x = 0.$$
   So your generalized eigenvalue problem is in fact just an eigenvalue problem.
2. [removed as per the comment below.]
3. The equation $n_R+2n_C=N$ looks quite strange to me. First, although complex eigenvalues do come in pairs, this does not mean you should multiply $n_C$ by 2; it merely means that $n_C$ is even. Second, it looks as though you are treating this equation as a fact. But even in the case $B=I$, and even if we correct to $n_R+n_C=N$, this is a nontrivial assumption! In that case it is precisely the statement that $A$ is diagonalizable.
4. If we do not change the equation, then it is an even more stringent condition. For instance if $B=I$, it implies that precisely $n_C$ of the eigenvalues are repeated. I am curious to see what examples you have in mind.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Eric. The product of two symmetric matrices is not necessarily symmetric (this is the statement that symmetric matrices do not form a group under metric multiplication).

Comment: Ah thank you, that was a silly oversight. But because point (3) still stands, I would still like to see at least one of the examples you had in mind.

Comment: I have given an example in the main body of the question. I hope this helps clarifying what I have in mind. I will think a bit more about your comment 3. Thanks for our help!